# syntax error when delete sql data using php

Tags: php, sql

im getting the following syntax error can someone please help!
im guessing it something soooo easy but i have been looking at it for ages and can see what im doing wrong

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
$dbhost = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$CourseId = $_POST['CourseId'];

$sql = "DELETE  course ".
       " WHERE CourseId = $CourseId" ;

mysql_select_db('d11os_projectdb');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>`enter code here`
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM course...` you need to tell it "from".

Comment: Sidenote: Your code is open to [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) and for so many reasons.

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM  course ".       --<-- Missing key word FROM
       " WHERE CourseId = $CourseId"
```

Comment: It could have taken this person 2 seconds to google this. But I guess when you dont even know what to google its a bit hard :)

Comment: Well we all have been there :) I am still there though lol :)

Comment: Cheers Rahul thank you for you input will keep this in mind for next time :P

Comment: just kidding, nice catch though +1

Comment: i have made the following changes 

    $sql = "DELETE ROW FROM course WHERE CourseId = $CourseId";

but am now getting this error????

Could not delete data: Unknown column 'G4NC' in 'where clause'

i need it to allow the user to type in a course id and then delete the row

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the table name from the sql query

```
$sql = "DELETE  course FROM **table_name**".
       " WHERE CourseId = $CourseId" ;
```

Comment: im still getting the same error when i do the following

$sql = "DELETE * FROM course WHERE CourseId = $CourseId";

Comment: $sql = "DELETE  course FROM **table_name**".
       " WHERE CourseId = '$CourseId' " ; you have to also put single quotes on $CourseId

Comment: Yea that sorted it thank you for your help my delete button now works :)